# How did I cast more than 40 votes in a single day?

Tags: support, voting

My [profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) says I voted 41 times today. But we only get up to 40 votes/day. So how can this be?

Could this have happened due to undownvoting (or unupvoting) a post, and getting a vote back? I don't recall having uncast any votes today.

Could it be from voting on a post that was subsequently deleted? I think I did that today.

Comment: MAGIC. Sounds like a bug, don't worry about it.

Comment: Because you're special :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That happens if one of the post you voted on is deleted. So, technically you did vote 41 votes. But only 40 of the posts exist in the site at the moment.

From [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

> Votes on deleted posts do not count towards your daily total.
>
> xxxxxx did indeed vote 42 times in one day: two of the target
>   posts were deleted before the day ended, allowing him to have those
>   two extra votes.